# Re Order List Numbering VSTO

Tags: c#, vsto

I am working on hiding 2 bullets of numbered list in Microsoft word document using VSTO(C#).
I am successful in hiding the bullets but i want to re arrange the bullets numbering after hiding.
Does someone has any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is to use some library where you can apply conditional content. So if you have a document, which would be your template, you can define parts of this document to either be displayed or not in your final document. You can see some examples [here](http://www.docentric.com/documentation/examples/conditional-content). Your final document is plain .docx and will contain only those conditional contents that match the criterion. It will therefore not hide some content but it will simply not include it, if it doesn't match - and thus the numbering of list items will be correct.